# How to Continue the Iteration If one string is not valid?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I am new to this programming and package and have no idea why I am getting this error. Does anybody have any idea about this?

```
zeep.transports: HTTP Response from https://www.marktstammdatenregister.de/MaStRApi/Api.svc/Soap11/Akteur (status: 403):
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode>s:Receiver.FalscherMarktakteur</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="de-DE">Die Funktion kann mit den angegebenen Zugangsdaten nicht verwendet werden, da der Marktakteur nicht gültig ist oder dafür nicht verwendet werden kann</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
'''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lakshman.Krishnan/PycharmProjects/untitled/01_final_MaStR/help.py", line 107, in <module>
    c = c.GetMarktakteur(apiKey=apiKey, marktakteurMastrNummer=myMastrNr, mastrNummer=i)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.8\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 45, in __call__
    kwargs,
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.8\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 130, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.8\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 195, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.8\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 299, in process_error
    detail=fault_node.find("detail"),
zeep.exceptions.Fault: <exception str() failed>
```

Comment: Usually you are getting errors because something is not good with your code. If you don't post here the relevant code, other people could not help you with fixing it.

Comment: Translating the error message reads something like *"The function cannot be used with the specified access data because the market player is not valid or cannot be used for it"*. Seems that you are calling an operation of the SOAP web service but you are sending it wrong or invalid parameters. You need to show some of the code you are using and preferably also the relevant part of the service's WSDL file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in a loop that contains an if-else statement, you can use try-except to handle exception:

```py
try:
    # Your logic

except:
    continue  # In case of a error continue to the next iteration
```

Example (although this example does not throw an exception but you can see how to implement try-except):

```py
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print(i)
    except:
        continue
```

Instead of "continue" you can print the error or other operations too.